How to index 1000 .py files in multiple subdirectories to a vector database & make RAG leverage the folder structure?
There 1000s of .py files from 20 different projects. The directory structure is as follows
code base root folder
* common libaries1
* common libaries2
* common libaries3
* project1
* project2
* project3
* .... ........
* projectN

What is the best strategy to index/chunk the codes to a vector database (pgvector) so that RAG uses the folder structure (multiple projects and common libaries) while answering the questions?
Just dumping 1000s of files in a single root folder does not sound like a good startegy since folder stucture information is lost.

vector DB (e.g. ChromaDB or Weaviate) can effectively index 1000 .py files across multiple subdirectories and leverage the folder structure for RAG.
1. Install libraries
Install libraries like chromadb and langchain for document loading, text splitting, embedding generation, and vector database interaction.
pip install chromadb langchain

2. Initialize the vector database client
Initialize a ChromaDB client to interact with the vector database. This client  allow to perform operations like querying, and managing data within the DB.
from chromadb import Chroma
chroma_client = Chroma()

3. Embedding Model
Choose embedding model (e.g. sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2 model) that will convert text data from Python files into numerical vectors.
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings

embedding_model = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

4. Load & Split Python scripts
Iterate through the directory to find Python files. Split large files into smaller chunks for efficient embedding generation
import os
from langchain.document_loaders import PythonFileLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

def load_and_split_files(file_path):
    loader = PythonFileLoader(file_path)
    documents = loader.load()
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=50)
    return text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

5. Generate Embeddings
For each chunk of text, generate an embedding using the embedding model. It convert textual data into numerical vector that can be stored in vector database.
6. Index Chunks into Vector DB
Insert text chunks and embeddings into the vector DB, including metadata for efficient querying.
7. Query Vector DB
To retrieve relevant code chunks, generate an embedding for the query text. Use the vector DB client to perform a similarity search, which will return the most relevant chunks based on the query embedding. The results can be filtered based on metadata, such as project name, to leverage the folder structure.
8. Leverage the Folder Structure
By including metadata like the file path and project name, query results can be filtered based on specific projects / directories. it allows to retrieve relevant code chunks not just based on content similarity but also based on their origin within folder structure.
